MSI Installer for newer versions of Python
Sorry, am a newbie looking for advice on how to build an MSI official release installer for Python (e.g. Python 3.9.20). I've Visual Studio installed but am not sure how to move forward from there. Thanks!
I downloaded Visual Studio 2022 with the 'Python Development' and 'Desktop development with C++' workloads installed (image attached).
Then, I followed the instructions on the Tools/msi/README.txt file. It mentions that I need to set the following environment variables:
set PYTHON=<path to Python 2.7 or 3.4>
    set SPHINXBUILD=<path to sphinx-build.exe>
    set PATH=<path to Git (git.exe)>;
             <path to HTML Help Compiler (hhc.exe)>;%PATH%

Does this mean that I need to download Python 3.4 in my computer first, as well as Git and Sphinx in order to build the official release installer?
I have also executed the batch file Tools\msi\get_externals.bat in the command prompt and it ran without error (image attached).
I then executed this command in CMD: build.bat --pack and the build failed with the following 3 error messages. Understand that I'm not supposed to use this for release builds but I tried this option as I wasn't sure what to do with the environment variables, which is not needed for build.bat.
EXEC : error : Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bl
urb (from versions: none)
EXEC : error : No matching distribution found for blurb
error MSB3073: The command ""C
:\Users\<myusername>\Desktop\Python310\cpython-3.10.15.tar\cpython-3.10.15\cpython
-3.10.15\externals\pythonx86\tools\python.exe" -m pip install -U blurb" exi
ted with code 1.

